# Promise with jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise, es6-promise

I have a preloader using Promise and I'm interested if it's possible to implement the same with jQuery?

```
var Preloader = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // Variables
    var $preloader = $('#preloader'));


    function init() {
        $preloader.delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
        resolve();
    }


    $(window).on({
        'load': function() {
            init();
        }
    })
});
```

and I use like this:

```
Preloader.then(function() {
    SomethingElse();
}, function(error) {
    //error
});
```

So I'm calling SomethingElse only when Preloader has finished? Any advice/code for jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is only a javascript library.. It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: If the task of Preloader is only to call delay() and fadeOut() before calling resolve(), you can simply pass resolve as a callback function to fadeOut().